# How to edit comment_reply_link

Tags: login

I was editing a wordpress theme. Where i need to replace default wp login link with custom login link.

Problem is, `comment_reply_link()` function is returning the default link. And i dont want to edit wp-include/comment-template.php

Is there any other way, so that without manipulation of any wordpress file i can replace the default login url.

I already had tried

```
apply_filters('login_url', $login_url,get_permalink());
```

before `calling comment_reply_link()`. But it is not filtering resulting URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple make a check if user is logged in and show him the reply button, if is not you can show him a custom link to your login file.

something like this:

```
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/login"><?php _e('Reply', 'artdev'); ?></a>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php comment_reply_link() ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you copy/pasted wrong line or misunderstanding how to add filter. [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) runs actual hook, to attach your function to the hook you use [`add_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

It should be something like that:

```
add_filter('login_url','custom_login_url');

function custom_login_url($login_url) {

    return 'your url';
}
```